# Composing a tile's texture coordinates using GLSL

Tags: algorithm, opengl, glsl, shader, vertex-shader

### Preface

Consider the following example image:

[image: Tilesheet Example]

Note the following:

- Each tile index increments from left to right, top to bottom
- There are only 28 valid tiles (out of a possible 32)
- In this example, we know that each tile is 32x32 in pixels
- We also know the overall image dimensions are 256x128 in pixels

---

### Question

Given only the above info and a valid tile index, how could we use a vertex shader to construct the proper texture coordinates to use for a desired tile, which would then be passed to the fragment shader for sampling? Luckily, we can make use of `gl_VertexID` to identify which 'corner' of the image we need... But since we are working with normalized textels (instead of just pixels), we'll need some way of scaling things down between 0 and 1, which further complicates the algorithm.

Here's what I have so far, though it only seems to display a solid color from the image

```
#version 330 core

layout(location=0) in vec3 in_pos;
out vec2 out_texCoord;

void main()
{
    // These will eventually be uniforms/attributes, and are
    //  only used here for more immediate debugging purposes
    int tileNum = 1;        // Desired tile index
    int tileCount = 28;     // Maximum # of tiles
    float tileWidth = 32;   // Width of each tile in pixels
    float tileHeight = 32;  // Height of each tile in pixels
    float imgWidth = 256;   // Overall width of image in pixels
    float imgHeight = 128;  // Overall height of image in pixels

    // Attempt to calculate the correct texture coordinates
    //  for the desired tile, given only the above info...
    int tileIndex = tileNum % tileCount;
    int columnCount = int(imgWidth / tileWidth);
    int rowCount = int(imgHeight / tileHeight);
    int tileX = tileIndex % columnCount;
    int tileY = int(float(tileIndex) / float(columnCount));

    float startX = float(tileX) * tileWidth;
    float startY = float(tileY) * tileHeight;
    float endX = 1.0f / (startX + tileWidth);
    float endY = 1.0f / (startY + tileHeight);
    startX = 1.0f / startX;
    startY = 1.0f / startY;

    // Check which corner of the image we are working with
    int vid = gl_VertexID % 4;
    switch(vid) {
        case 0:
            out_texCoord = vec2(startX, endY);
            break;
        case 1:
            out_texCoord = vec2(endX, endY);
            break;
        case 2:
            out_texCoord = vec2(startX, startY);
            break;
        case 3:
            out_texCoord = vec2(endX, startY);
            break;
    }
    gl_Position = vec4(in_pos, 1);
}
```

---

### Disclaimer

Before anyone comes barging in talking about a lack of info/code, please note that using the following code does indeed properly display the entire image, as expected...
Effectively, this means that there is something wrong with the actual texture coordinate calculations,
and not with my application's OpenGL implementation:

```
int vid = gl_VertexID % 4;
switch(vid) {
    case 0:
        out_texCoord = vec2(0, 1);
        break;
    case 1:
        out_texCoord = vec2(1, 1);
        break;
    case 2:
        out_texCoord = vec2(0, 0);
        break;
    case 3:
        out_texCoord = vec2(1, 0);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inverting a texture coordinate seems to be a shot in the dark. You just need to scale it down:

```
float endX = (startX + tileWidth) / imgWidth;
float endY = (startY + tileHeight) / imgHeight;
startX = startX / imgWidth;
startY = startY / imgHeight;
```

Comment: Hrmm.. well, it does display a tile. Just not the correct ones.
It starts off on the first tile, as expected... However, it's as if the tile index is skipping an arbitrary number of tiles per increment. So perhaps we're missing something else here...

Comment: Do you increment by changing `tileNum`? Are you drawing a single quad at once? I'm not sure if the `int(.)` operator behaves like you expect. It might be worth a try using the plain cast operator `(int)(.)`. Not sure though. Can you output the `tileIndex`, `tileX` and `tileY` as a color and check if there values seem reasonable?

Comment: Before my last comment, I had already checked if `tileIndex` was incrementing properly in the shaders by setting all fragments to red when `tileIndex > 5` (as well as simply setting it directly to a desired value within the vertex shader itself). In both cases, `tileIndex` was correct. I haven't _internally_ checked `tileX` or `tileY` yet, but I've graphed it out and used a calculator to make sure I was using the right equations for them, which I was. Also, GLSL doesn't allow C-style casts (you'll get an error after compiling/linking the shaders), so I know that's not the issue either.

Comment: Now you can see why I've been stuck on this for so long... The solution seems so simple, and I'm sure it actually it is something insanely simple, and yet the actual answer somehow eludes me. Quite the conundrum!

Comment: How are the tiles jumping? Can you post, in which order the tiles appear when you increment?

Comment: It seems rather arbitrary to me (back and forth, out of sequence), but if you'd like the exact values, give me a few minutes and I'll post another comment with them using the example texture at the top of my question

Comment: Using the syntax of [TileIndex = "DisplayedImage"]:
`0="1", *1="5", 2="9", 3="25", *4="13", *5="21", 6="1", 7="9", 8="17", *9="21", 10="25", 11="1"`, etc...
Using the example texture, I happened to noticed something...
The pair of numbers above with an asterisk before them appear to show the image with a slight offset of one or two pixels on the left (as if the image were shifted to the right). Curious....

Comment: Oops, nevermind the comment about the askterisks... I mistakenly set the `imgWidth` value in the shader to be 258 instead of 256. However, after correcting this issue, those same arbitrary tile values above come up all the same (just, without the above mentioned 'offset' artifact). So the main issue still exists...

Comment: Hm.. the offset is always a multiple of 4. Do you have the chance to debug the shader? I usually don't use OGL, but DX, so I can't help you there. Could you try leaving the `% tileCount` away? I have the feeling that the problem is caused by one of the modulos.

Comment: HAHA! Well for some reason, that was the culprit... I'm not sure what I changed (or where, or exactly when), but it would appear that the vertex shader isn't receiving the correct `tileIndex` value. After removing the modulus, and setting tileIndex directly, it works as expected... So now I just need to find out why it isn't being passed correctly into the shader, and all is good. Thanks!

Comment: Just an FYI... I found the issue.
For GLSL, after you bind an attribute with `glBindAttribLocation`, you're supposed to link the program again. Seems redundant to me but hey, whatever works.